# Python: Remove specific character from dataframe column value

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe with Column[ID] and values ('123456','102554','0145220','1554201','0155401','0101010110','0101010105')
If last 2 characters of the column starts with 0 then update the value without that 0

Final result of dataframe should be   ('123456','102554','0145220','155421','015541','0101010110','010101015')

Please help

Answer (score 3):

You can leverage `pd.Series.replace(..., regex=True)`:

```py
df["ID"] = df["ID"].replace("^(.*)0(.)$", "\\1\\2", regex=True)
```

Outputs:

```py
           ID
0      123456
1      102554
2     0145220
3      155421
4      015541
5  0101010110
6   010101015
```